# how to import the a file in child page in php?

Tags: php, include

I am new to php, my root path is `bill/bill/index.php`, in `index.php` I am including the `bill/bill/Home/checksession.php`

In `checksession.php` I have write a line `header('Location: logout.php')`, If I include the `checksession.php` from the Home folders files, It show error path `bill/bill/logout.php` (It is write), but also I need to include the `checksession.php` from Home folder php files.

Comment: `location: /logout.php`

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question, sorry for my bad english.